# Fullcalendar events get squeezed horizontally

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

There are lots of events in my web application and I utilize the Fullcalendar library to display them. However, events get squeezed horizontally sometimes, even if there is be more space available.

Please see this screenshot of squeezed events in Fullcalendar:

[image]

As you can see, the 9:00am to 9:30am event is very wide, while four events starting at 8am are squeezed right next to it.

What could I do to prevent this squeezing? I tried changing the order in which the events are loaded into Fullcalendar, but this does not change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest there's not really a lot you can do, unless you want to re-write fullCalendar's internal event rendering engine.

You can probably mitigate it a bit by setting

```
slotEventOverlap: true
```

in your calendar options - although this is the default anyway, so presumably you've already overriden it. But this will cause events to overlap each other horizontally (by up to half), thus saving some horizontal space.

More info: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap